# Add gradient to UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, gradient

I have a `UIScrollView` that scrolls horizontally. And I have added some `UIButtons` into it. Now I want to add a little gradient to the 2 buttons those are in the start and end point of the `contentOffset`

[image]

If you can see above image there is a little gradient in 2014 button.
How can I add that to my button.
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32283/core-graphics-tutorial-lines-rectangles-and-gradients

Answer (score 0):

It might be difficult to add gradient to the buttons.

Rather create a UIView of width say 40 and place it on top of scrollView at both ends. Set a transparent gradients on these two views.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a transparent image and put it above the button. see here in image.

[image]

Here I created transaparent image and put on uibutton. but make sure you disable the "User Interaction Enabled" property of UIImageView from attrivute inspector. otherwise button click event not get called.